# Grouping by multiple years in a single column and plotting the result stacked

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this, with the default pandas index starting at 0:

```
index     Year    Count    Name
0         2005    70000    Apple
1         2005    60000    Banana
2         2006    20000    Pineapple
3         2007    70000    Cherry
4         2007    60000    Coconut
5         2007    40000    Pear
6         2008    90000    Grape
7         2008    10000    Apricot
```

I would like to create a stacked bar plot of this data.
However, using the df.groupby() function will only allow me to call a function such as .mean() or .count() on this data in order to plot the data by year. I am getting the following result which separates each data point and does not group them by the shared year.

[image]
I have seen the matplotlib example for stacked bar charts, but they are grouped by a common index, in this case I do not have a common index I want to plot by. Is there a way to group and plot this data without rearranging the entire dataframe?

Comment: Sort by area first and then plot? There will be no special separation but identical areas will be grouped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could do this using `pivot` first:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Count', index='Year', columns='Name')
df1.plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]
Or with the argument `stacked=True`:

```
df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I imagined how I could rotate the data to work in excel, but not how to do so with Pandas, much appreciated.